# How do I make a Function available everywhere

Tags: php, cakephp

I would to create a function/class that would be available in model, view and controller in cakephp. How do I go about it? Where do I create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[/app/config/bootstrap.php](http://book.cakephp.org/view/954/Bootstrapping-CakePHP) is meant for such functions, but as the manual says:

> Be careful to maintain the MVC software design pattern when you add things to the bootstrap file: it might be tempting to place formatting functions there in order to use them in your controllers.
>
> Resist the urge. You’ll be glad you did later on down the line.

If you have more extensive functions or classes you can use the [vendors directory](http://book.cakephp.org/view/943/Loading-Vendor-Files), especially if you use third party libraries.

Comment: what do u think of ------"To create a class you can use from anywhere, put a file in APP/libs (for example my_class.php), make a class in it (like "class MyClass"), and then import it wherever you want to use it (using "App::Import('Lib', 'MyClass');")."

Comment: and could you elaborate your note(resist the urge)

Comment: @WebDeveloper you are breaking the pattern by doing that.

Comment: The note means that controllers, models and views have very clearly defined boundaries and they rarely overlap, so if you find that you need to use a (formatting) function in each of them you're working against the MVC pattern.

Comment: Agreed with the pattern breaking. I've never had a reason to need something across all three. @Web Developer, maybe if you shared your desired functionality it would be more obvious why you would need that.

Comment: i wish to use htmlpurify in some cases before saving to db and at other cases while echoing